# The new cocos2d has not got CCRibbon?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocos2d-iphone, 2d-games

I recently downloaded the new cocos2d (I still have the older one) and I have been using a ribbon from CCRibbon to make a bullet move but it does not exist anymore and in a lot of my games it is a key object, can I somehow put it back in or use a similar "drawing" object?

Thanks.

Comment: Yup, it's gone. Depending on how you used it, you may be able to use CCMotionStreak. But it's not a 1:1 replacement.

Comment: I used it to look like a fast moving bullet at any angle, i.e I create the bullet, place it somewhere, get rid of it, place it a bit further etc.. How does CCMotionStreak work?

Comment: i m going through same problem .. i also have latest cocos2d v2.x version . & i m unable to use ccribbon in my game ... how it possible that in newer version . you cant have the functionalities which is available in old one !!!!