# How to draw a simple line in Cocos2d v2?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In a follow on to my last question, [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588470/the-new-cocos2d-has-not-got-ccribbon) to replace CCRibbon I want to draw a simple line. How can this be done? (By the way I have looked at other previous questions but I still cannot get it)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Draw Primitives tests in the cocos2d project. In short you can use the following code.

Inside the draw method of the node

```
-(void)draw
{
    [super draw];

    ccDrawColor4B(255, 255, 255, 255) //Color of the line RGBA
    glLineWidth(5.0f) //Stroke width of the line
    ccDrawLine(ccp(0, 0), ccp(10, 10));
}
```

Comment: thanks this works :) but can i not run these lines of code anywhere else? for example in:

Comment: -(id) init
{
 // always call "super" init
 // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
 if( (self=[super init])) {
 }
 return self;
}

Comment: No they rely on the fact that they are in draw which is called every frame. You could draw them to a CCRenderTexture in init if you wanted.

Comment: Thats a big question! Have a look at this http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches/

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in v3